# How to navigate list through keyboard up/down events

Tags: lightning-web-components

This is the piece of code

```
<div class="datacss">
 <ul>
     <template  for:each={nameslist} for:item='item'> 
         <li key={item} data-value={item.Name} onmousedown={handleMouseDown}> {item.Name} </li>
   </template>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am having two issues here

1. onclick event is not working in my li tag. Instead using onmousedown events, it is working but not onclick event
2. How to make my list navigate through keyboard up and down events, if users click on down then first  list item should get focus, if users click down again then second list item should get focused. and so on.. And vice versa for up arrow

I am trying with onkeyup but unable to achieve the work.

Any ideas to help.

Answer (score 0):

To detect weather user has presses arrow keys, you need to use [onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) Event.

- The onkeydown event occurs when the user is pressing a key (on the keyboard).
- Tip: The order of events related to the onkeydown event:

  - onkeydown
  - onkeypress
  - onkeyup
- The keycodes are:

  ```
  left = 37
  up = 38
  right = 39
  down = 40
  ```

you can have a look on this:- [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

You can then  add your logic to these event handlers.